# Domino OSGi servlet <contextRoot>

Tags: java, servlets, osgi, lotus-domino

When writing a Domino OSGi servlet you need to specify a context root for your web application. This is done in plugin.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="com.ibm.pvc.webcontainer.application">
      <contextRoot>
         /exporter
      </contextRoot>
      <contentLocation>
         WebContent
      </contentLocation>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

1. Does the context root need to be unique for all OSGi servlets running on the server?
2. Where can I find documentation?

Comment: I have not used the `com.ibm.pvc.webcontainer.application` extension point and, like you, I can't find any documentation on it.  But there is another way to create an OSGi servlet in Domino.  You can extend `org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets`.  That's how the DAS servlet is implemented.  Have you tried this alternate extension point?

Comment: I haven't and to be honest I don't know how to... What would be the advantage? Could I also use Jax-RS with Equinox?

Comment: The advantage is there is better documentation out there.  And, Yes, your plugin can both implement the equinox extension and use JAX-RS.  But since you are building a REST API, there is also a third option.  Your plugin could simply extend the DAS servlet.  You can add your JAX-RS resource classes to DAS as described here:  https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Create_your_own_Domino_REST_service_using_DAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.  Context root needs to be unique.
2. I can't find any useful documentation on the `com.ibm.pvc.webcontainer.application` extension point.  As I mentioned in the comments, I recommend you instead use the `org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets` extension point.  That's how the DAS plugin implements a servlet (see [the DAS plugin.xml](https://github.com/OpenNTF/XPagesExtensionLibrary/blob/master/extlib/lwp/product/runtime/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.domino.das/plugin.xml)).  Both extension points are defined by OSGi plugins Domino inherited from elsewhere.  That's why the Domino documentation doesn't cover them, but I think you will find more documentation on the `equinox` extension point.  For example, see Paul Fiore's [Domino OSGi Development](http://www.slideshare.net/fiorep/domino-osgi-development) slide deck.  That includes a whole section on creating a servlet.